# Phpmyadmin - How to let users create and manage their own databases without allowing them to see other databases

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In PhpMyAdmin I want to allow certain users the ability to create and manage databases without having to manually give them permission to every database they need. I've noticed when giving a user the ability to create databases they are able to see other databases they don't have permission to. I'd prefer if they were only able to see the ones they have permission.

I've looked about online for what I need, I couldn't seem to find anything. Any help in finding something (if it exists) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.  The `CREATE TABLESPACE` permission assumes the user is a server administrator.  You might get a different response by asking this question in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the below step for the access and manage the database

Click on the "Add a new User link"
Assign the User a login and password.
Where it says "Database for User" select "None"
Leave all checkboxes in global privileges unchecked.
Press the "Go" button.